# Find cluster of points in adjacency list

Tags: matlab, adjacency-list

**Problem**

I have an adjacency list roughly 67 000 x 5. Some example data is shown below. Column 1 is displaying the point and column 2-5 are containing all neighbours of each point. Zeros are non-existing points.

```
A= 1 50 3 86 4
   2 1701 11 19 1001
   3 1 0  100 88
   4 999 765 34 1 
   etc.
```

Now I have a second set of points in my case 1256x1 but lets assume for the example it is something like this.

```
B= [ 1 2 3 4 11 34 55 etc.]
```

**What I would like to have**

Now I am looking for cluster of my dataset B in A, meaning I want to find all points of B that are connected within my adjacency list. So as that for the example

```
C1=[1 3 4 34]
C2=[2 11]
```

Is there any smart way to solve this ? I am completly stuck, I am not even really sure where to start. Thanks for your help!

**Edit**

[How can I cluster points which are connected in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294610/how-can-i-cluster-points-which-are-connected-in-matlab)

Different to the question posted above I am not looking for a cluster within my Edgelist but I want to specifically test if my second data set B contains points that are neighbors/ clusters. I know that my dataset A is one big cluster - it is an undirected graph, basically a rectangle and every node is connected to its surrounding nodes and hence all blocks can be reached without violating edge constraints.

Is there away to adapt the algorithm described in the link above to find clusters of data set B in A?

Comment: A common way of finding connected components of a graph is doing BFS or DFS. Do you need this kind of graph traversal?

Comment: You can either filter your adjacency list to contain only nodes in `B`, or mark nodes *not* in `B` as visited, before performing DFS.

Comment: Thank you, that was a useful comment!